# How to optimize / order a table in SQL Alchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to optimize a table in SQL Alchemy in Python ?
(SQL Lite)

How can we proceed ?
Is it necessary to order by date to improve performance ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do performance tuning it to start from database level, sqlalchemy or whichever program you use the extract the information will find an easier schema to work with.

Once your database schema is clean, you can now look at specific queries and how to implement them. Adding ordering on queries will not improve performance

This link might give some insights optimizing SQLlite
https://katastrophos.net/andre/blog/2007/01/04/sqlite-performance-tuning-and-optimization-on-embedded-systems/

Comment: Mean compress or order the table does not improve perf ?